# Ideal way to monitor MOS scores with pfSense based routers

Tags: networking, router, pfsense, voip, rtp

We currently have well over 200 pfSense routers in deployment at locations around the world running around 10,000 VoIP phones.

Our issue is we need a way to monitor MOS and other QoS aspects and receive alerts should a threshold be reached. This gives us a head start of issues before they start.

Basically, we just need ways to better diagnose and track down issues that effect RTP and VoIP based technologies.

So far I've found minimal to nothing with pfSense that helps in this regard.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most accurate VoIP QoS metrics you have are measured by your VoIP endpoints.

You can intercept transparently all RTCP traffic between the VoIP endpoints on your routers, then parse the RTCP packets – see [RFC 3611](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3611), [RFC 7266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7266).